# Rewrite plpgsql function to sql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, plpgsql

Is it possible to rewrite the following plpgsql function as a sql function?
I'm using it to aggregate my data by most recent timestamp, but wish to deploy on heroku which doesn't support plpgsql.
I could totally rewrite my original query that uses this function, but I'd like to keep the flexibility for being able to drop in other aggregate functions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recent_accum(anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS $$
     BEGIN
        IF $1.tstamp IS NULL and $2.tstamp IS NOT NULL
           THEN RETURN $2;
        ELSEIF $1.tstamp IS NOT NULL and $2.tstamp IS NULL
           THEN RETURN $1;
        ELSEIF $2.tstamp > $1.tstamp
           THEN RETURN $2;
        ELSE RETURN $1;
        END IF;
     END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work to rewrite the IF/ELSEIF chain using CASE?

```
CASE
WHEN $1.tstamp IS NULL AND $2.tstamp IS NOT NULL
     THEN $2
-- ...
ELSE $1
END
```